# DateTime.Parse Not Parsing

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I'm trying to return the date as "2015-06-18"

```
string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
```

This returns "2015/06/18 hh:mm:ss"

What am I missing?

Comment: whats wrong with the result?  what are you expecting?

Comment: And _how_ are you looking at the result? In the debugger? In that case, you're looking at it in the default format, which may very well be different from `yyyy-MM-dd`. The `DateTime` data type is not a string. It's binary.

Comment: sorry, am mixing literal and <T>. What is being returned is "yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss". What i want is "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: it is made up of the Date and TIme, it wont drop the Time portion if that is what you want.  use `newDate.Date`

Comment: What "this" returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a particular output format, you can specify one yourself.

```
string strDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
DateTime newDate = DateTime.Parse(strDate);
string output = newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
Console.WriteLine (output); // produces 2015-06-18 right now
```

The `DateTime` structure in .net always includes the time of day, and there is no built-in way to store only a date, so if you want to exclude it, you'll need to use the formatting options.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to format the `datetime` object.

```
newDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") -> 2015-06-19
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the DateTime.Date property?

```
    DateTime date1 = DateTime.Now;
    Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString());

    // Get date-only portion of date, without its time.
    DateTime dateOnly = date1.Date;
    // Display date using short date string.
    Console.WriteLine(dateOnly.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"));
```

Comment: If you use the "d" format string, then there is no reason to go to the trouble of getting `.Date` since the time will be stripped off in formatting anyway.  And "d" is locale-dependent, but the question wants the date in a specific format.